# Google Cloud - Apache, Application & Cloud Sql

Tags: sql, cloud

I would like to build a high performance and reliable setup using Google Cloud Infrastructure but I'm confused where to start and what are the services I should use from there that suits the setup I want to build.

My setup has 4 areas:
1. http server will be accessed by hundreds of users in parallel.
2. This http server running translates the users requests and commands to database queries and pushes through through the application which provided the web interface.
3. Sql database... while this database is accessed ONLY by the application running on the apache server.
4. Big storage to save icons and swatches/images for each database entry (also the application itself can be placed here).

I used to build such setup locally, but it would appreciated if anybody ware of google infrastructure can advice me for the best combination of google cloud products/services that I can use for building such setup the way it give the most possible performance.

Thanks in advance